# Can QGIS table editor achieve similar results to Pivot tables in Excel?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table

Is it possible to achieve similar results to Pivot Tables in QGIS table editor so as to use just QGIS instead of several software solutions? Or are there maybe some plugins capable of achieving those dynamic results?

Comment: I don't know about the dynamic part, but the [GroupStats](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) plugin should offer pivot table capability.

Comment: GroupStats works great for generating pivot table style results, and it is very easy to use.  You can quickly export your results as a CSV as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamic part isn't really doable without actions or triggers (or some other workaround) - that's one of the key differences between a database and a spreadsheet. However, there is a plugin for QGIS that provides pivot table functionality called [GroupStats](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/).

As an aside for any Arc user who comes across this, ArcGIS has a [Pivot Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n8000000) tool at the Advanced license level.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot to with a Virtual Layer.

I have a point table with a category field (forest, water, swamp), and a value field.

I want to pivot the table and calculate sum of value, per category.

```sql
SELECT
    sum( CASE WHEN "category"='forest' THEN "value" ELSE 0 END ) AS forest_sum,
    sum( CASE WHEN "category"='water' THEN "value" ELSE 0 END ) AS water_sum,
    sum( CASE WHEN "category"='swamp' THEN "value" ELSE 0 END ) AS swamp_sum
FROM randompoints
```

The layer created with automatically update when you modify the original table.

[image]